C++ Linker cannot find reference to class method
I never seem to be able to correctly split and manage my C++ projects that have multiple files. So excuse my ignorance...
I'm receiving these linker related errors from g++ when trying to compile the project:
/usr/bin/ld: main.o: in function "main":
main.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to "AVLTree<int>::AVLTree()"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x35): undefined reference to "AVLTree<int>::inserir(int)"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x46): undefined reference to "AVLTree<int>::inserir(int)"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x52): undefined reference to "AVLTree<int>::print()"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x5e): undefined reference to "AVLTree<int>::~AVLTree()"
/usr/bin/ld: main.cpp:(.text+0x87): undefined reference to "AVLTree<int>::~AVLTree()"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status


The command I'm using to compile is: g++ -o program src/main.cpp src/arvore.cpp -I include
I'm also trying to run it on VSCode, using the compile&run button. It gives the same error as when I try compiling in the terminal.
My folders are structured like this:
Image of the folder structure
One thing before I show the code for the files: I'm a portuguese speaker, that's the language the comments and most of the methods are written in. I know there's a lot of comments and we should keep them brief... there's so many of them because I'm writing them to help me understand what's going on as I'm a newbie and studying as I write the code
arvore.hpp
#ifndef ARVORE_H
#define ARVORE_H

template <typename T>
class TreeNode{
    
    T dado;
    TreeNode* esquerda;
    TreeNode* direita;
    int altura;

    public:
        TreeNode(T dado);

};

template <typename T>
class AVLTree{
    private:
        TreeNode<T>* raiz;

        int getAltura(TreeNode<T>* no);

        int getFatorDeBalanceamento(TreeNode<T>*no1, TreeNode<T>*no2);

        TreeNode<T>* rotacionarEsquerda(TreeNode<T>* no);
        
        void atualizaAltura(TreeNode<T>* no);

        TreeNode<T>* rotacionarDireita(TreeNode<T>* no);

        TreeNode<T>* balancearNo(TreeNode<T>* no);

        TreeNode<T>* inserirNo(TreeNode<T>* node, T dado);

        void delecaoRecursiva(TreeNode<T>* node);

        void printRecursivo(TreeNode<T>* node);
    
    public:
        AVLTree();

        void inserir(T dado);

        ~AVLTree();

        void print();

};
#endif

arvore.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "../include/arvore.hpp"

template <typename T>
TreeNode<T>::TreeNode(T dado){this->dado = dado; esquerda = nullptr; direita = nullptr; altura = 1;}

template <typename T>
int AVLTree<T>::getAltura(TreeNode<T>* no){
    if(no == nullptr)
        return 0;
    return no->altura;
}

template <typename T>
int AVLTree<T>::getFatorDeBalanceamento(TreeNode<T>*no1, TreeNode<T>*no2){
    return getAltura(no1) - getAltura(no2);
}

template <typename T>
TreeNode<T>* AVLTree<T>::rotacionarEsquerda(TreeNode<T>* no){
    //deve ser passado como argumento o nó que tem o valor de balanceamento diferente de 1,-1 ou 0.
    TreeNode<T>* novaRaiz = no->direita; //a nova raíz (nó mais alto) será o filho à direita do desbalanceado
    no->direita = novaRaiz->esquerda; //o nó pai deixa de apontar à direita (para o filho), que agora é a nova raíz. Passa a apontar para o nó à esquerda do filho
    novaRaiz->esquerda = no; //o antigo filho passa a apontar para o pai, fazendo assim ele "subir" e se tornar a nova raíz

    atualizaAltura(no);
    atualizaAltura(novaRaiz);

    return novaRaiz;
}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::atualizaAltura(TreeNode<T>* no){
    //vai atualizar a altura atual do nó (os nós folhas tem altura 0, enquanto a raíz tem a maior altura)
    //lembrando que a altura da árvore é definida como o número de nós no maior caminho da raíz até uma folha
    //utilizar getAltura evita o uso de um operador ternário para tratar o caso das nodes da esquerda ou direita serem nulas
    no->altura = 1 + std::max(getAltura(no->esquerda) ,getAltura(no->direita));
}

template <typename T>
TreeNode<T>* AVLTree<T>::rotacionarDireita(TreeNode<T>* no){
    //deve ser passado como argumento o nó que tem o valor de balanceamento diferente de 1,-1 ou 0.
    TreeNode<T>* novaRaiz = no->esquerda; //a nova raíz (nó mais alto) será o filho à esquerda do desbalanceado
    no->esquerda = novaRaiz->direita; //o nó pai deixa de apontar à esquerda (para o filho), que agora é a nova raíz. Passa a apontar para o nó à direita do filho
    novaRaiz->direita = no; //o antigo filho passa a apontar para o pai, fazendo assim ele "subir" e se tornar a nova raíz

    atualizaAltura(no);
    atualizaAltura(novaRaiz);

    return novaRaiz;
}

template <typename T>
TreeNode<T>* AVLTree<T>::balancearNo(TreeNode<T>* no){
    //o fator de balanceamento é sempre a altura da sub-árvore da esquerda menos a altura da sub-árvore à direita. Isso porque se a direita for maior, vai dar um número
    //negativo, que é a norma para indicar um desbalanceamento à direita
    //vai retornar o nó balanceado, para ser o novo apontado
    int fatorDeBalanceamento = getFatorDeBalanceamento(no->esquerda,no->direita);

    if(fatorDeBalanceamento > 1){
        //caso de desbalanceamento à esquerda (a árvore da esquerda está mais pesada)
        if(getAltura(no->esquerda->esquerda) >= getAltura(no->esquerda->direita)){
            //caso de rotação simples à esquerda (não existe filho à direia do filho à esquerda que seja mais pesado que o seu irmão à esquerda)
            return rotacionarDireita(no);
        }
        else{
            //caso de rotação dupla à esquerda (rotação esquerda-direita)
            no->left = rotacionarEsquerda(no->esquerda); //primeiro vai colocar tudo depois do filho esquerdo à esquerda
            return rotacionarDireita(no); //depois rotaciona à direita
        }
    }
    if(fatorDeBalanceamento < 1){
        //caso de desbalanceamento à direita (a árvore da direita está mais pesada)
        if(getAltura(no->direita->direita) >= getAltura(no->direita->esquerda)){
            //caso de rotação simples à direita (não existe filho à esquerda do filho à direita que seja mais pesado que o seu irmão à direita)
            return rotacionarEsquerda(no);
        }
        else{
            //caso de rotação dupla à direita (rotação direita-esquerda)
            no->direita = rotacionarDireita(no->direita); //primeiro vai colocar a sub-árvore à direita na direita
            return rotacionarEsquerda(no); //depois rotaciona à esquerda
        }
    }

    //se não estiver desbalanceado
    return no;
}

template <typename T>
TreeNode<T>* AVLTree<T>::inserirNo(TreeNode<T>* node, T dado){
    //Vai retornar um nó pois se trata de uma função recursiva

    if (node == nullptr){
        return new TreeNode<T>(dado); 
        //se apontar para o nulo, vai retornar um novo nó, inserindo uma nova folha com sucesso
    }

    if (node->dado < dado){
        //se o dado a ser inserido for maior, vai percorrer a sub-árvore à direita. Quando chegar ao nulo, vai retornar tudo.
        node->direita = inserirNo(node->direita, dado);
    }

    if(node->dado > dado){
        //se o dado a ser inserido for menor, vai percorrer a sub-árvore à esquerda. Quando chegar ao nulo, vai retornar tudo.
        node->esquerda = inserirNo(node->esquerda, dado);
    }

    //atualiza a altura das folhas até a raíz
    atualizaAltura(node);

    //como é recursivo, vai balancear todos os nós até chegar na raíz, que vai ser balanceada e retornada como valor de root, quando chamamos inserir()
    return balancearNo(node);
}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::delecaoRecursiva(TreeNode<T>* node){
    if (node != nullptr){
        delecaoRecursiva(node->esquerda);
        delecaoRecursiva(node->direita);
        delete node;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::printRecursivo(TreeNode<T>* node){
    if (node != nullptr){
        std::cout<<node->dado<<"\t";
        printRecursivo(node->esquerda);
        printRecursivo(node->direita);
    }
}

template <typename T>
AVLTree<T>::AVLTree(){raiz = nullptr;}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::inserir(T dado){
    //Vai começar a inserção pela raiz
    raiz = inserirNo(raiz, dado);
}

template <typename T>
AVLTree<T>::~AVLTree(){
    //Destrutor, deve deletar todos os nós da árvore utilizando o algoritmo post-order
    delecaoRecursiva(raiz);
}

template <typename T>
void AVLTree<T>::print(){
    printRecursivo(raiz);
}


main.cpp
#include "../include/arvore.hpp"

int main(void){
    AVLTree<int> a;
    a.inserir(5);
    a.inserir(2);
    a.print();
}

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's something stupid.
Tried compiling it from VSCode. Thought the command I was using to compile from terminal might have been wrong. Was surprised to find out VSCode gave out the same error.

Put all the template code in arvore.hpp file, throw away arvore.cpp. You cannot put template code into cpp files unless you use explicit template instantiation, which doesn't seem applicable to this case.
